# Convert hours into week,days,hours in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-4, preg-match-all

1. User has given input `2w2d2h` in input field.
2. In database it is showing `386`.
3. `2w=2*24*7`
4. `2d-2*24`
5. `2h=2`
6. After adding above three value it become `386`.
7. Now from database when I will fetch `386` it should show `2w2d2h`.

Please help me out

Till now I have inserted value after conversion.

```
preg_match_all('#(\d[wW]+|\d[dD]+|\d[hH]+|\s+)#i', $category, $matches);
$hours = 0;
$days = 0;
$hoursss = 0;
foreach ($matches[0] AS $match) {
    switch(true) {
    case preg_match('/\d[hH]+|\s+/', $match):
        $hours += (int)$match;
        break;

    case preg_match('/\d[dD]+|\s+/', $match):
        $days += (int)$match * 24;
        break;

    case preg_match('/\d[wW]+|s+/', $match):
        $hoursss += (int)$match * 24 * 7;
        break;
    }
    $case = $hours + $hoursss + $days;
}
```

Comment: I am note sure you have actually made your question clear. What is it you actually want help with?

Comment: `/\d+[wdh]/i` would be a simplified versions of your regex. I am not sure you even need to use regular expressions for this; at least not to the extent you are.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will convert number of hours onto the expression you need:

```
$hours = 386;
$weeks = floor($hours / (24*7));
$hours -= $weeks * 24 * 7;
$days = floor($hours / 24);
$hours -= $days * 24;

printf("%dw%dd%dh", $weeks, $days, $hours);
```